# Resharper marks my NUnit tests as unused

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and NUnit 2.6.3 together with Resharper 8.2

Resharper recognizes my Unit tests (so I can run them with Resharper) but yet they are all marked as unused (classes as well as the individual test methods). I know how to suppress the warning with a comment at each test class but I am looking for a solution without such comments because they also affect test code that is really unused (and thus I should be warned).

From my understanding this should work out of the box for NUnit tests but I can't manage to make it work. Do I have to change some settings? I googled quite a while but didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you saying that Resharper marks the code as unused?

Comment: Yes, I just clarified it in the question.

Comment: Did you decide to make the classes `internal`? Because with an `internal` class ReSharper might check your assembly and determine that the class is never used, but with a `public` class ReSharper might say, "fine, this is for use by code I can't see from here." I can understand if you took the explicit decision to keep test classes `internal`, but did you?

Comment: No, the classes are public. From my undestanding Resharper should be smart enough to ignore the fact that the class is not referenced because of the [TestFixture] annotation, regardless of its visibility.

Comment: But how can ReSharper complain with `public` stuff. Will it complain with the code `namespace N { public class C { public void M() { } } }`? Because it cannot know if some consumer of the code (elsewhere) is going to say `var c = new N.C(); c.M();` since both `C` and `M` are `public`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It seems to check usage within the current solution.

Comment: Have you tried my example with `N`, `C`, `M`?

Comment: Acutally it is not a warning but the class and method names are greyed out.

Comment: Yes, I tried it (and it is also marked as unused).

Comment: Have you go the `[Test]` attribute on each test?

Comment: Yes, a [TestFixture] attribute on the class and [Test] attributes on each test method.

Comment: Can't reproduce with NUnit 2.6.3 and Resharper 8.2.1, once the `[Test]` attribute is added Resharper does not show the code as unused.. that's in VS2013 though. - http://postimg.org/image/681rgwd0d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install ReSharper ExternalAnnotations to solve the problem. VS2008 does not support ReSharper Extension Manager, so please install it manually:

1. Download [nuget package](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations/8.2.0.2719);
2. Open it using any archiver software like WinZip;
3. Extract all folders from `..\ReSharper\vAny\annotations\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\ExternalAnnotations`;
4. Then restart Visual Studio;