# Resharper 8.2 String.Format "remove item at index" context action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I am having problem after new Resharper 8.2 update that in String.Format method if I have arguements then the argement list is not getting hilighted and context action like "remove item from at index" is not showing when I selet the argment. Everthing was workign fine before, I have not seen any bug reported on Resharper regarding that. I have tried  to restart computer and visual studio but with not success. Is anyone had the same problem? I am using visual studio 2008.

Please see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2008 does not support ReSharper Extension Manager, so you need to install ReSharper ExternalAnnotations manually to solve the problem:

1. Download [nuget package](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations/8.2.0.2719);
2. Open it using any archiver software like WinZip;
3. Extract all folders from `..\ReSharper\vAny\annotations\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\ExternalAnnotations`;
4. Then restart Visual Studio;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've got the annotations extension installed. Go to ReSharper -> Extension Manager, Online -> Bundled Plugins and check that the `ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations` extension is installed (it'll have a green check next to it). If not, install it.

The `string.Format` highlighting relies on the annotations to know that it should apply the actions and highlighting to the method parameters.

Comment: Matt, he uses VS2008, so there is no chance to find Extension Manager in ReSharper menu. I guess the solution here is - install ExternalAnnotations manually as I described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735896/resharper-marks-my-nunit-tests-as-unused/23738723#23738723

Comment: @Alexander: The solutions you provided worked for me, may be can put your solution to seperate answer so I can mark it as answer. Thanks.